# Can I reduce/change the margins given in the template of a journal?

Tags: publications, journals, formatting

Recently, my paper has been accepted in a journal(ENDM). They asked to reduce the number of pages. When I used their template, it exceeded the number of pages allowed. I tried my best to reduce the number of pages, but no use.
Can I reduce/change the margins given in the template of a journal to reduce the number of pages. Is it ethical to do so? Will they reject my manuscript?
(manuscript has been accepted after minor changes).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The entire point of the template is to make certain that everybody is on the same page (no pun intended) as to what the format is. Changing it defies this purpose and will almost certainly be noticed – if the journal uses this template for production at all.

While nobody except the journal staff knows how exactly they would react to what you intend to do, I would prophesy that **at best** they directly return the manuscript to you and ask to properly shorten your manuscript.

Answer (score 12):

> They asked to reduce the number of pages.

Then do it.

If your article complied with the journal's instructions before peer-review but now breaks them because you added extra content asked by reviewers, you could write a short note to the editor saying the requested edits forced you to write a longer version. If they ask you to comply, then you have no choice but to edit your paper accordingly. Don't fiddle with the template.

> Is it ethical to do so?

That's irrelevant. Such rules are practicalities of each journals and ethics have nothing to do with it.

This being said, editing out portions of the article *after* the final review is generally forbidden. If you make significant changes to the content, I suspect the article will have to be reviewed again.

Answer (score 8):

### Margins are important for typesetting

When preparing an actual journal edition, they're not going to use your document as-is, they are going to put it in their typesetting process (whatever that might be) anyway.

The only reason why a journal is asking you to use a particular template is so that you (and they) can see what the layout would be. Altering that template to have reduced margins would mean that in the "preview" version you have the required number of pages, but in the actual end product the number of pages and layout is different than expected - which is not a good thing, because (1) it comes as an unpleasant last minute surprise; (2) it's malicious, caused by a deliberate attempt to circumvent their guidelines. The result may vary, but it certainly won't be viewed positively.